# Problems after updating swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have recently updated swift and I use a sidebar framework. Now when I load it, I get the following errors:

```
 override init() {
    super.init()

}

init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>){
    super.init()
    originView = sourceView
```

It highlights on the `super.init()` lines with this error:

```
property self.originView not initialized at super.init call
```

and highlights the `originView = sourceView` with

```
Immutable value self.originView may only be initialized once.
```

I'm not sure what's wrong because it's not my code and I need it to work. Any suggestions would be highly valued :)

Comment: *Exactly* the same question about the same code was asked 6 hours ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift you have to init your property `self.originView` like

```
class MySwiftclass: NSObject {
var originView = UIView(....)
}
```

or you can write

```
class MySwiftclass: NSObject {
var originView: UIView!
}
```

or you can write

```
class MySwiftclass: NSObject {
var originView: UIView?
}
```

Comment: I will accept the answer is four minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

In the library code, `originView` is probably set as constant (`let`). Change it to `var` and see if it works.